# what if an operating system can change your password

Tags: password-management

Everyone want security for their pc/laptops... NO DOUBT...

So we protect them by some password. 'Longer password, more security' this is the tag line. But what if our computer can change our account's password?

For better security, can we design an OS which is able to change our passwords with specific duration of time???  It means our password will vary with that given duration of time... It will make a cycle between our passwords...

When anyone try to break the password he prefers to use different different combinations, by changing passwords time to time will lowers the probability of finding the correct combination.

Will it be useful for security purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An implementation of what you suggest has been a round for a while: it's called [SecurID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID)

The clocks are synced and the token ID and clock are used to create a time-limited password unique to the token. In essence, an ever-changing password.